# Agregar información extra en la respuesta Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

Mi problema es que quisiera agregar información extra al momento de enviar la respuesta a la función

```
function totalKey(line) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        Key.countDocuments({ 'line': line }, async (err, count) => {
            resolve(count);
        })
    });
}
```

Lo que quisiera hacer sería el conteo en Key que contengan la misma clave de linea en cada una

```
listLineTotalKey(req, res) {
    Line.find({}).sort('_id').exec(async (err, line) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Internal Server message' });
        if (!line) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Line Not Found' });
        return res.status(200).send({
            data: line.map(async l => {
                return {
                    _id: l._id,
                    count: await totalKey(l._id)
                }
            })
        });
    });
},
```

Estaba pensando en hacer un map regresando el objecto en si, pero me regresa

[image: Explicación de respuesta]

Objectos vacíos :c

**Actualización**

intenté hacer lo siguiente

```
async function totalKey(lines) {
    return Promise.all(lines).then(line => {
        return line.map(l => {
            let aux = {};
            aux._id = l._id;
            aux.count = Key.countDocuments({ 'line': l._id });
            return aux;
        });
    });
}
```

Pero me envía el error siguiente

```
(node:8248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'NativeTopology'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'topology' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (D:\Node\catalogo\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1123:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\Node\catalogo\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:260:14)
    at ServerResponse.send (D:\Node\catalogo\backend\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:158:21)
    at D:\Node\catalogo\backend\src\controllers\line.js:55:36
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5
```

Comment: no puedes usar async con map. Para poder hacer un map de promesas puedes usar `Promise.all([promesas])`

Comment: Pero ¿cómo @ajuni880? Ya intenté hacerlo pero me manda un error :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer algo parecido a esto. No estoy seguro si esta la solución correcta.

```
function totalKey(line) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        Key.countDocuments({ 'line': line._id }, async (err, count) => {
            resolve({
                _id: line._id,
                count
            });
        })
    });
}
```

```
listLineTotalKey(req, res) {
    Line.find({}).sort('_id').exec(async (err, line) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Internal Server message' });
        if (!line) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Line Not Found' });
        const promesas = line.map(l => totalKey(l));
        const data = await  Promise.all(promesas)
        return res.status(200).send({ data });
    });
},
```

Comment: Oh sí, muchas gracias c: Que amable, eres lo mas